# Angular 2 SVG CSS rendering differently inside component

Tags: css, svg, angular

Transferring some designs to Angular 2 and am using the following code snippet:

```
<svg class="header__icon help__icon" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
  <use xlink:href="images/icon/info-help_small.svg#help__icon"></use>
</svg>
```

When I use this code outside of the angular component with the exact same stylesheet applied the SVG element scales properly, but as soon as I add it to the inside of an Angular component, no scaling occurs at all.  Is this an Angular issue?

This is an image of outside the Angular component with same styles:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dja36.png]

This is an image of the SVG inside Angular component:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIRdA.png]

Comment: How do you scale it? What styles are you using? Please provide more information that allows to reproduce?

Comment: SVG is case sensitive so try viewBox rather than the incorrect viewbox.

Comment: renaming "viewbox" to "viewBox" fixed this.  Not going to lie, I probably wouldn't have even tried this because it was working in normal html mode.  If you submit this as answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
<svg class="header__icon help__icon" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
  <use [attr.xlink:href]="images/icon/info-help_small.svg#help__icon"></use>
</svg>
```