# Vis.js Graph2d doesn't display correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, vis.js

I'm trying to use vis.js in javascript. I have successfully displayed a graph3d. But, when i'm trying to add a graph 2d (the first graph2d showed as example on visjs website) it doesn't display correctly and i have this warning : "Something is wrong with the Timeline scale. Limited drawing of grid lines to 1000 lines."

Thanks for you help,
Ludo

Comment: I guess you run into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564122/angular-2-svg-css-rendering-differently-inside-component but your question doesn't provide enough information to know. I don't know Graph2d.

Comment: I just have copy/paste this example from : http://visjs.org/graph2d_examples.html

Comment: This is a better link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265026/angular-2-innerhtml-styling.

Comment: Can you creat a Plunker that allows to reproduce? https://plnkr.co/edit/zE3Byu?p=info

Comment: I'm not an expert i don't know how to reproduce it with a Plunker. To sum up : I have installed the library vis.js. I'm trying to use one of its functions to display a 2d graph. The graph appears but the axis are not at the right place and the curve is out of my screen.

Comment: you might need to import css for the library if you didn't